# Location manager show bad location in gmsMapView swift 4.2

Tags: swift, google-maps, delegates, cllocationmanager, gmsmapview

I have a problem that a I cannot resolve. I'm trying to get the current location to update the mapview and center the camera, but when I close the view controller and init a new Mapviewcontroller the "current location" show a location incorrect, near to my position but not the current location. Can anyone guide me o help me? this is my code:

```
class MapContainerViewController: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var myLocation: CLLocation?
var autorizeChange: Bool?
var geofire: GeoFire?
var createGeoforme: Bool?
var INITIAL_CENTER: CLLocation?
var searchCircle: GMSCircle?
var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    autorizeChange = true
    checkLocationServices()
    createGeoforme = false
    mapView.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }


 func setupLocationManager(){
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func checkLocationServices(){
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        setupLocationManager()
        checkLocationAutorization()
    } else {

    }
}

func checkLocationAutorization(){
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        //Do map stuff
        if (mapView.isMyLocationEnabled == false ){
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
            var ref: DatabaseReference
            ref = Database.database().reference()
            geofire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref)              

        }
        break
    case .denied:
        //Show alert instructing
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        //location manager
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
    case .restricted:
        //Show alert letting them know
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break
    default:

    }
}
}

}

extension MapContainerViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate{

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) 
 {
    mapView.clear()
    let coordinate = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.center)
    var cooordinate2d = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    var circ = GMSCircle.init(position: coordinate, radius: zoomLevelToRadius(zoomLevel: Double(position.zoom)))
    circ.fillColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.15)
    circ.strokeColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.15)
    circ.strokeWidth = 0.5
    circ.map = mapView;

}

func zoomLevelToRadius(zoomLevel: Double) -> Double{
// Approximation to fit circle into view
    return (16384000/pow(2, zoomLevel))
}
}

extension MapContainerViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: location, zoom: 14)
    let centerLocation = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.center)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAutorization()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code can be your solution you can find here https://github.com/SwiftGuides/Google_Place_Picker

This is sample code i wrote for Google place picker to pick exact pin point custom location (not nearby location)

In your case you can apply this too. Just check the example code you will get you solution